# Unable to run byfn.sh up

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to run Hyperledger Fabric's byfn on Amazon lightsail instances. I have ran the following launch script:

```
curl -o lightsail-compose.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KY-Leung/Catena/master/setup/lightsail-compose.sh

chmod +x ./lightsail-compose.sh

./lightsail-compose.sh

curl -o /fabric-setup.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KY-Leung/Catena/master/setup/fabric-setup.sh

chmod +x ./fabric-setup.sh
```

Subsequently, I SSH-ed into the isntance and executed the follwing:

```
/fabric-setup.sh
cd fabric-samples/first-network/
./byfn.sh generate
./byfn.sh up
```

However, the following error occured:

```
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.0
Creating network "net_byfn" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer1.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer1.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ...
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ...
Creating orderer.example.com    ...
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ...
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ...
./byfn.sh: line 151:  9978 Killed                  IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGETAG     docker-compose -f $COMPOSE_FILE up -d 2>&1
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
```

I tried to google but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Following are the versions:

```
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the Docker containers for errors?  The 'byfn' network is a multi-org multi-peer Fabric running with SSL enabled.  You could teardown all the containers etc, and try the 'basic-network' first which is very simple and might make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Also check how much resource (Memory etc) you've got available/allocated in your Lightsail instance (you don't give any information on your spec: Lightsail memory/disk/OS version, node version etc.

Comment: Thanks @PaulO'Mahony, I was using instance with 512 MB RAM, 1 vCPU, 20 GB SSD. After upgrading it to 8GB RAM, 2 vCPU, 160 GB SSD, byfn runs perfectly. Currently I'm doing it trial and error, finding the minium requirements